# automatically register GCE instances in google cloud DNS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-dns

How do I have my GCE instances register with an internal GCP DNS zone? Is there a built in way to do this?

Edit: looks like I can do this https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dns/record-sets/transaction/add

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case in details? By *register*, do you mean to create a [managed DNS zone](https://cloud.google.com/dns/zones/) and host an application or website in your GCE VM using the DNS resolution of that?

Comment: I mean the instance registers a DNS record for itself in an internal zone

Comment: There is an open feature request for this, maybe upvote it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904549

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a full guide on this, check out [Google Cloud Platform in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/google-cloud-platform-in-action).

You can use the Cloud DNS API to register the instance, which is pretty straight forward. I think the part that isn't well documented would be how to get the right IP address and such in a start-up script.

The following code snippet has some helpers in Node.js that pull down instance names, zones, and IP addresses which you can then use to register with Cloud DNS.

```
const request = require('request');

const metadataUrl = 'http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/';
const metadataHeader = {'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google'};

const getMetadata = (path) => {
  const options = {
    url: metadataUrl + path,
    headers: metadataHeader
  };
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (err, resp, body) => {
      resolve(body) ? err === null : reject(err);
    });
  });
};

const getInstanceName = () => {
  return getMetadata('instance/name');
};

const getInstanceZone = () => {
  return getMetadata('instance/zone').then((data) => {
    const parts = data.split('/');
    return parts[parts.length-1];
  })
};

const getInstanceIp = () => {
  const path = 'instance/network-interfaces/0/access-configs/0/external-ip';
  return getMetadata(path);
};

const getInstanceDetails = () => {
  const promises = [getInstanceName(), getInstanceZone(), getInstanceIp()];
  return Promise.all(promises).then((data) => {
    return {
      name: data[0],
      zone: data[1],
      ip: data[2]
    };
  });
};
```

So then in Cloud DNS, you could register using these helpers by doing something like the following (note this was written using an early version of the DNS library -- you can install it by running `npm install @google-cloud/dns@0.6.1`).

```
const dns = require('@google-cloud/dns')({
  projectId: 'your-project-id'
});
const zone = dns.zone('mydomain-dot-com');

getInstanceDetails().then((details) => {
  return zone.record('a', {
    name: [details.name, details.zone].join('-') + '.mydomain.com.',
    data: details.ip,
    ttl: 86400
  });
}).then((record) =>{
  return zone.createChange({add: record});
}).then((data) => {
  const change = data[0];
  console.log('Change created at', change.metadata.startTime,
              'as Change ID', change.metadata.id);
  console.log('Change status is currently', change.metadata.status);
});
```

Comment: How you do it with gcloud cli?

Comment: Found a doc. Gcloud is already installed and it simple command so preferable to writing code

Comment: You can get your desired metadata by [querying metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata#querying) from **within the associated instance**. For your specific query of internal IP address I found that this curl works fine.  `curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/network-interfaces/0/ip?recursive=true&alt=text" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"`

Comment: I've had the opposite experience, the API is usually more stable and deprecations are announced ahead of time, while the CLI is constantly making breaking updates. Node.js cloud platform API and docs https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-node  
docs: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/libraries

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want an internal DNS registration, in which case this happens automatically. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns.

For example, if you create an instance named "instance-1", it will be automatically resolvable from any instance in the same network and project as either `instance-1` or the FQDN: `[HOST_NAME].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal`.

Note: automatic external DNS registration is now in alpha: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904549

Comment: Has there been any update on external DNS registration?